# how do we ensure a badge doesn't penalise a behaviour you might be trying to encourage?

Tags: discussion

For the [`Electorate` badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/155/electorate) I have voted on close to 2K out of 600  but only 15% vs 25% were on the question instead of the answer.  If I had voted 1/4 as much on the answers but 1/2 as much on the questions, I would get this badge.

From scratch, the minimum number of questions I would need to vote on would be 150, but for me to get this badge I now need to vote on 220 questions, and stop voting on answers.

Is there a logic to this?

Comment: You could also vote on questions even more.

Comment: @Cerbrus I have to vote on more questions than a newbie would. SO even though I have voted ~2K times, in some ways I am worse than starting from scratch.

Comment: You are doing it wrong, the badge was meant to encourage voting on questions so the system gets a better signal.  Up *and* down.  You don't DV nearly enough.  Finding a poorly asked question never takes an effort.

Comment: I'm guessing that there is a lot more voting on answers than questions and they're trying to encourage people to vote on questions more.

Comment: @HansPassant good point. Plenty of those every day.  I prefer to give a helpful comment and be constructive.

Comment: I really don't see how you could have a problem finding enough questions to vote on. There are plenty of good (and _bad_) guestions that could do with a up (/down) vote. You can still vote _and_ comment to be constructive.

Comment: That's up to you :)  It doesn't help the other thousands of SO users though.

Comment: @HansPassant my point is that I have voted on 300 questions already, double the minimum required.

Comment: I might be remembering things wrong but don't you get extra votes each day for voting on questions after you used up the normal votes?

Comment: I am not sure asking if the badge should make sense is useful.  I was just wondering....

Comment: Out of `12,698` votes cast by you, only a measly `116` are downvotes. If you don't want to downvote (and apparently are hesitant to vote on questions), why should you be awarded with a badge?

Comment: The badge does make sense if they're trying to make sure people vote on questions.

Comment: @BSMP I have, double the minimum required.  The problem is I voted too much on the answers as a ratio.

Comment: @Cerbrus note, the minimum number of votes is just 600.

Comment: The entire point of the badge is to make people vote on questions, which appears to be something you're actively avoiding... So you didn't get the badge...

Comment: _I voted too much on the answers as a ratio._ Yes, exactly. You're not being penalized for the good behavior of voting on answers, you're being penalized for the bad behavior of not voting enough on questions.

Comment: @Cerbrus The minimum number of votes on questions is 150, I have votes on 300.  How is that avoiding anything?

Comment: When only 2k out of your 12.5k of votes cast are on questions, I just get the impression you don't like voting on questions...

Comment: @Cerbrus 2k votes on questions when the minimum number of votes for the total is just 600.  Not sure it's making any more sense to me.

Comment: And when questions aren't helpful, you should downvote them. My current vote count, for example: `665` up, `1,528` down. Total votes: `2,193` (`914` on questions, `1,279` on answers). There's plenty of stuff out there to downvote.

Comment: Never the less it does mean that if you vote a lot but in the wrong ratio, you are worse off than someone starting from scratch.

Comment: Sure, but it that a problem on SE's side, or is that a problem with the voting behavior of the user?

Comment: To get 2K of 12.5K up to 3.2K of 13.7K I have to vote another 1200 times, but if I started from scratch it would be 600 time.

Comment: @Cerbrus that depends on what the point of the badge is.  Is it to encourage people to vote on questions and answers as the name suggests, or it to enforce an expected ratio.

Comment: The point of the badge is to encourage people to vote on questions. [You'd better get to work, then](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/8153/worst-case-scenario-how-long-until-the-electorate-badge?userid=57695).

Comment: @Cerbrus Yesterday I was contacted by another forum with the tag line "an ambitious community without power-trippin' mods and noob-stompin' haters"  Clearly enough people hate hit and run downvoting.

Comment: Anyone can create a website with an opinion like that. Tell me, how big is it's userbase? Sure, noone likes being downvoted, but if you can't handle being downvoted, or don't want to downvote because it doesn't seem "nice", then don't dv. Just don't expect to get all the badges if you don't use the site to it's full potential.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To simplify things, I'm going to reiterate the criteria:

> Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions.

This does indeed reward a behavior pattern that we want to recognize, people that actually vote on questions. This is also why down-votes on questions don't cost the voter a penalty - folks were voting pretty heavily on *answers* well enough, but we weren't getting signal that we needed on questions.

***This might not be a badge that fits the way you use the site, and that's fine.***

If you tend to vote more on answers as you drill down, that's *fine*, don't stop what you're doing. Please remember to give the question a vote, too - it's just as important to recognize good stuff as it is to bury bad stuff. But, don't let aspirations for a certain badge make using the site *uncomfortable* for you.

Summarizing it:

- Everyone was voting on answers. Not many were voting on questions
- We provided additional incentive to vote on questions, and adjusted how rep worked a bit to make it easier
- That doesn't mean we don't need people that really drill down into the technical merits of answers, we need those people badly.

Should we have a counterpart where we basically take the criteria for the badge and `s/questions/answers/g`? I'm open to the proposal. Since *quite* a few people vote in that pattern, it wasn't something we thought we'd need to incentivize - we tend to provide incentive mostly when incentive seems needed, which generally isn't when "that's what everyone is pretty much doing now" :)

It's fine to want all the badges, but the way everyone uses the site individually is more important because the way that varies balances everything. If scoping a badge makes using the site seem uncomfortable, it's .. just not the badge for you. They're not Pokemon ;)

Comment: I wonder, once you get the badge, will you lose it again if you get below the 25%, or is it permanent?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If the point of badges is to encourage, it shouldn't overly discourage a behaviour you want to keep.  IMHO The problem with hit and run down voting on questions is that is disadvantages new questioner who don't know how to ask a good questions and may never learn if all they get is "kicked off the system"  If you look at the number of downvoted questions I have *commented* with the intent of encouraging better behaviour and learn how to ask a question, it would be in the hundreds easily.

Comment: @Cerbrus It won't be revoked. It's awarded when you meet the criteria.

Comment: I down vote when the person should know better and already should know what they are doing wrong. e.g. repeatedly asking a bad question they have already been told is bad, or asking for homework. If I think they are just missing something basic they could learn from, I comment instead.

Comment: "people that actually vote on questions"  I have 300 votes on questions. If I had another 200 votes on questions, it wouldn't make a difference.  Unless I am careful I could have more than 600 votes on questions...

Comment: Peter, we don't mean to put things out of reach, but a _lot_ of patterns when it comes to voting on questions fell into "always" or "never". That doesn't in any way diminish how you use and benefit the site, it just means that you're describing a use case that we might, in fact, want to reward with another badge. Do you mind if I dig into your use history as a model (privately) in order to consider it some more?

Comment: For my use case, it might be comments on downvoted questions. To make sure the Electorate badge is not out of reach you could put a requirement cap of 600 questions. i.e. if you give at least 600 votes on questions, you still get it even if you vote a lot on answers.

Comment: I also comment early on a lot on upvoted questions to give other people a chance to answer it so they get credit. Quite a few people have mentioned to me in person they won't answer a question if they see I have answered it already.  Not sure this should be a badge.

Answer (score 3):

You're not being penalized for the good behavior of voting on answers, you're being penalized for the bad behavior of not voting enough on questions.

They want people to vote on questions at least 25% of the time. If they made the requirement to just vote on N number of questions, you'd just vote on N questions and then stop which isn't what they want. They want you to vote on a question for at least every 3 votes on answers.

The answers wouldn't exist on the site at all if someone didn't ask the question first and up-voting them encourages people to keep asking good questions. Down-voting bad questions gets them off the web site and discourages people from posting them in the first place. Voting on questions is an important part of how the quality of the site is maintained; it makes sense that there would be a badge for people that regularly vote on questions.

Comment: Not voting enough on questions isn't _bad_ behavior, not getting a badge isn't being penalized. Badges are artifacts you pick up on an adventure, our system lets users choose their own - so naturally, chasing them all will sometimes lead to mutual exclusion.

Comment: I have voted on twice as many questions as someone who might achieved the minimum.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Compared to someone that votes just as often as you do on a daily basis, a low percentage of your votes are on questions. You've been a member for over 6 years now. Vote _count_ is pretty insignificant.

Comment: @TimPost - I was just using the same language the OP used. I agree that it's not really a penalty to not get a badge. Do you think I should edit the answer to reflect that?

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Your percentage is too low. They want people to be voting on questions at least 25% of the time.

Comment: @BSMP That is clear, but clearly arbitrary. The actual number doesn't matter too much.

Comment: @BSMP I think our comments are sufficient, if you'd like to change your answer that's up to you. Philosophically, we _reward_ what we want in hopes of getting more of it and [avoid any kind of punishment whenever possible](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/). It is a system based on positive reinforcement. This is meta, so - well, make sure your answer reflects how you think and feel.  I don't think you've reached too far.